# problemwith tab index in windows application user control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, user-controls, windows-authentication

I create an user control that has some textbox and buttons.the problem is when I use tab to traverse in My form when my usercontrol get focus the focus go inside of user control and buttons insid if it would focus.How I can simply go to next control after my user control not inside it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controls have `Focusable` `CanHaveFocus` `TabStop` sort of properties, set them to false.

Also set the `TabIndex` properties of those controls to 0. I'm sure that the controls will be ghosts in terms of getting tab focus.

Answer (score 1):

Set `TabStop` property on your custom user control elements which you want to exclude (eg. your button) to `false`.